# React JS routing not working

Tags: reactjs, react-router, service-worker

Routing is working on development server but it is not working on production build at localhost.

```js
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import { Switch,BrowserRouter as Router,withRouter, Route, Link } from 'react-router-dom'
import Login from '../login'
import Home from '../Home'


class MyRouter extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <Router>
        <Switch>
          <Route exact path='/' exact component={Login} />
          <Route path='/Home' exact component={Home} />
        </Switch>
      </Router>
    )
  }
}

export default MyRouter
```

package.json

```html
{
  "name": "tutorials",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "homepage": ".",
  "dependencies": {
    "code-prettify": "^0.1.0",
    "react": "^16.3.0",
    "react-dom": "^16.3.0",
    "react-router-dom": "^4.2.2",
    "react-scripts": "1.1.1"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test --env=jsdom",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  }
}
```

and also it shows service worker not found.

[service worker.js not found](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9KT8c.png)

[But I am having service worker.js next to index.html in the build folder](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1ijeH.png)

Also, refer the home page in my package.Json

Finally, i am running the build application on xampp server in localhost

kindly let me know if I did anything wrong

Comment: Are you getting any errors in the console?

Comment: Can you post what your index.js looks like?

Comment: GET http://localhost/service-worker.js 404 (Not Found) I'm getting this error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have to suggest for run your build app u can maka virtual host for that using wamp/xamp server ex: myapp.local

OR

You can use

```
npm install -g serve
serve -s build
```

For build app and run your build app on Static sever 5000 port .

```
serve -h
```

for more details u can check above command.

Comment: Now the site is running perfectly in localhost:5000

Comment: one more query I am using php for database calls and i want to host this in php server. Is this will run on the server ? Or I want to use nodejs hosting. Guide me to host

Answer (score 0):

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import Home from './components/Home';
import Login from './components/Login';
import { BrowserRouter as HashRouter, Route, Switch } from 'react-router-dom';

class App extends Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <HashRouter >
                    <div className="container">
                        <Switch>
                            <Route exact path="/Home" component={Home} />
                            <Route exact path="/" component={Login} />
                        </Switch>
                    </div>
            </HashRouter>
        );
    }
}
export default App;
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you have to mistake import of your component

```
import Login from '../login' 
import Home from '../Home'
```

Try this one and let me check.

```
import Login from './login' 
import Home from './Home'
```

Comment: Im having routes.js in route folder and login.js in the login folder and home.js in the homefolder

Comment: So have define exact path of your component file

import Login from '../login/login.js' 

import Home from '../Home/Home.js'

Comment: In login folder I have named starting file as index.js so I imported as ./login. It works perfectly in development server

Comment: So i have suggest you have run your build app so u have to one server you can do that using virtual host in your wamp/xamp server you can also install sever something like that taht help to run our build app

Comment: I changed as u suggested and run build. While running the builded file using xammp in localhost i am getting Server-worker.js not found i have attached screenshot above